# How is it possible to make an app which can not be uninstalled android

Tags: android, uninstallation

I know this may not be possible. but I just found such an app. I can't uninstall the app, even not able to clear data, cache of the app an really this is not a system app. What this app does is just spam my phone with push notifications all time.

My Phone is not rooted!!

So my question is how is it possible to make such an app?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apps which have administrative permissions, which can be found under Setting > Security & Private > Device Administrator, cannot be uninstalled without revoking administrative permission.

Answer (score 2):

> The only way to make your application uninstallable ( You can't
>   really if the user is using a rooted phone) would be to install it
>   directly in Android bundle, pushing it via ADB (while rooted) to the
>
> /system/app
>
> directory...
>
> Then, it's in anyway possible for a dev with standard access to the
>   users phone.

Comment: My phone is NOT rooted.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend reading up on ROM development. What you need to do ise create a non rooted ROM that has the app you don't want to be uninstalled in the /system/app directory. All apps that ship with ROM's will be in that directory which is restricted. Because you can't write to that directory when you install a new app they get placed in the /data/app directory. So if you issue an update to the app then it will most likely get placed in the /data/app directory and the update can be uninstalled.

Your options are kind of limited.